# Create a package in sql statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i need to create a package on the Part_id. for each package P1,P2,P3,... 
if there is a true in P1 then i need to include the code in the package_code as shown and the same for the Description i need to do this in a sql statement.

```
Part_id code    Code_description    P1      P2      P3      P4      P5      P6      P7      P8      P9      P10     P11     P12     P13     P14     P15
85      19      D1                  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      34      D2                  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      CS      D3                  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      EP      D4                  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      MS      D5                  TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      XR      D6                  TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
85      BU      D7                  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE







 Packages   Part_id     Package_code                    Package_description 
 P1         85          19| 34| CS | EP | MS |XR |BU    D1 |  D2 | D3| D4 |D5|D6 |D7 
 P2         85          19|34|BU                        D1| D2 | D7 
 P3         85          CS|EP                           D3 |  D4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a wretched table design, but I'm assuming you have no control over that.

The first step to getting the result you want is to unpivot the P columns so that you can treat them as rows (I only went to P4.  I'll leave it to you to fill in the rest).  I put the results into a CTE.

```
with CTE(Part_id, code, Code_description, Package, Included) as
(
select Part_id, code, Code_description, Package, Included
from Part p
unpivot
(Included for Package in (P1, P2, P3, P4)) unpvt
)
```

The next trick is to create a delimited list of codes (based on the Included field) out of the CTE rows.  That is done like this:

```
STUFF((select ' | ' + c2.code from cte c2 where c2.Package = c.Package and c2.Part_id = c.Part_id and c2.Included = 1 order by c2.Code_description for XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '')
```

Yes, it's ugly, but SQL Server wasn't really designed to do this sort of thing.

The final query looks like this

```
select distinct c.Package, 
c.Part_id, 
STUFF((select ' | ' + c2.code from cte c2 where c2.Package = c.Package and c2.Part_id = c.Part_id and c2.Included = 1 order by c2.Code_description for XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '') Package_code,
STUFF((select ' | ' + c2.Code_description from cte c2 where c2.Package = c.Package and c2.Part_id = c.Part_id and c2.Included = 1 order by c2.Code_description for XML PATH('')), 1, 3, '') Package_description
from cte c
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ca24/1)